# Job inside transaction is not getting dispatched (beginTransaction)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have a unique requirement where a database-transaction must only be committed if a job is dispatched.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
   $notification = new MyNotification($data);
   $customJob = new CustomSendQueuedNotifications($notification);
   dispatch($customJob)->onQueue('my-queue'); // not dispatching the job
   Log::info('MyJob dispatched');
   DB::commit();
}
catch (\Throwable $th) {
   DB::rolleback();
   throw $th;
}
```

But if I use:

```
DB::transaction() {
   $notification = new MyNotification($data);
   $customJob = new CustomSendQueuedNotifications($notification);
   dispatch($customJob)->onQueue('my-queue'); // dispatching the job
   Log::info('MyJob dispatched');
}
```

then it adds to the queue but I lose the option of manually committing or rolling-back the transaction.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the culprit is this typo `DB::rolleback();` should be `DB::rollBack();`.

Comment: You can commit() before dispatch() to ensure that data is saved on DB